# queria saber como faço para que o stream continue executando

Tags: android

Olá, queria saber como faço para que o stream continue executando, mesmo se eu for pra outra tela, ou sair do aplicativo. Mais não sei como faço. Alguém me dê uma dica e exemplo. Obrigado

Estou usando classe do tipo Fragmen
Quando saiu pra outra activity já vi no log isso: W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released

```
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1aovivo, container, false);

    imgStream = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgStreamId);
    btnTocar = (ImageView)  view.findViewById(R.id.btnExecutarId);
    btnTocar.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    imgStream.setVisibility(imgStream.INVISIBLE);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    btnTocar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(estadoInicial) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }
                estadoInicial = false;
            } else {
                if(playPause) {
                    new Player().execute(stream);
                } else {
                    if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                }
                estadoInicial = true;
                playPause = false;
            }
            checkIsPlaying();
        }
    });
    checkIsPlaying();
    return view;
}

private void checkIsPlaying(){
    if(!estadoInicial) {
        btnTocar.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        imgStream.setImageResource(R.drawable.streaming_parado);
    } else {
        btnTocar.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.streaming).asGif().into(imgStream);
    }
}

class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    estadoInicial = false;
                    playPause = true;
                    btnTocar.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            prepared = false;
        }
        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        if(progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
        btnTocar.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        imgStream.setVisibility(imgStream.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.carregando).asGif().into(btnTocar);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Carregando Streaming...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "atc pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(estadoInicial) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "play-pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(estadoInicial) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(prepared) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Recomendo que leia sobre [services no android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Valeu cara, dei uma lida, mais fiquei um tanto perdido em como aplicalo dentro do meu codigo. Vou dar mais uma pesquisada e ver o que encontro.
mais quero pergunta mais uma coisa, nesse aplicação eu adicionei uma notificação, pra quando ele estiver execuntado mostra na barra de status, bom, oq eu não conseguir, fooi ao clicar nessa notificaçao abrir a aplicação, voce pode me dizer como ou tiver algum exemplo.

Comment: o metodo da notificação:
private void notificacao() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setSmallIcon( R.drawable.icon_notificacao )
                .setContentTitle( "RPfm 105.3" )
                .setContentText( "Ao Vivo" )
                .setAutoCancel( false );
        int id = 1;
        NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifyManager.notify( id, builder.build() );
    }